# How to trace file descriptor duplication?

Tags: bash, shell, files, strace

I am learning to use redirection. the typical operation is like below:

```bash
    command > file 2>&1
```

Refer to APUE 3.10 and 3.12, I think the critical syscall sequence is like below:

```
    open(file) == 3
    dup2(3,1)
    dup2(1,2)
```

To test my idea, I create shell script and execute it with strace command, my test.sh is below:

```bash
    #!/bin/sh
    echo 'hello'
    whatfuckis # For get a stderr
```

then I use strace command to trace system calls and signals

```bash
    strace -y -o trace.log ./test.sh > tmp.txt 2>&1
```

tmp.txt get the error message as expected. I can see many syscalls like(read, write, close, fcntl..etc) in trace.log, I even saw the result that file descriptor 2(stderr) is pointed to tmp.txt.

The problem is that I don't see the specific operation of file descriptor duplication like dup2, this is weired. How can I trace file descriptor duplication? the main information of the trace.log is as follows:

```
read(10</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/test.sh>, "#!/bin/sh\n\necho 'hello'\nwhatfuck"..., 8192) = 54
write(1</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "hello\n", 6) = 6
stat("/home/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/madhouse/Qt5.14.2/5.14.2/gcc_64//whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/madhouse/Qt5.14.2/Tools/QtCreator/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v12.22.5-linux-x64/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/madhouse/.local/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/games/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/games/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/snap/bin/whatfuckis", 0x7ffc61f2a380) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "./test.sh: 4: ", 14) = 14
write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "whatfuckis: not found", 21) = 21
write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "\n", 1) = 1
read(10</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/test.sh>, "", 8192) = 0
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

The log for aviro

```
167936 execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "./test.sh > tmp.txt 2>&1"], 0x7ffc000ac898 /* 76 vars */) = 0
167936 dup2(3</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, 1) = 1</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>
167936 close(3</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>) = 0
167936 dup2(1</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, 2) = 2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>
167936 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f67e121d850) = 167937
167937 execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], 0x55855ac8c2d8 /* 76 vars */) = 0
167937 write(1</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "hello\n", 6) = 6
167937 write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "./test.sh: 4: ", 14) = 14
167937 write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "whatfuckis: not found", 21) = 21
167937 write(2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>, "\n", 1) = 1
167936 dup2(10</dev/pts/2>, 1</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>) = 1</dev/pts/2>
167936 dup2(11</dev/pts/2>, 2</home/madhouse/Applications/Lab/tmp.txt>) = 2</dev/pts/2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You're performing the redirection on the `strace` command, so the redirection will be performed by your interactive shell, and `strace` will not be able to see relevant system calls.
2. The `dup2` system call is performed inside of the child before the command execution. By default, `strace` will not follow children of your commands, so you won't be able to see the trace of the child itself. You will need to add the `-f` flag to your `strace` to make sure it also follows the children.

Bottom line, in order to perform the intended check, you need to run:

```
strace -yf -o trace.log sh -c './test.sh > tmp.txt 2>&1'
```

Then you'll see your expected sequence:

```bash
$ grep -E 'dup2\(|clone\(|execve\(|(open|write|close)\(.*tmp.txt' trace.log 
31769 execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "./test.sh > tmp.txt 2>&1"], [/* 124 vars */]) = 0
31769 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ffff7fd19d0) = 31770
31770 open("tmp.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3</tmp/tmp.txt>
31770 dup2(3</tmp/tmp.txt>, 1</dev/pts/445>) = 1</tmp/tmp.txt>
31770 close(3</tmp/tmp.txt>)            = 0
31770 dup2(1</tmp/tmp.txt>, 2</dev/pts/445>) = 2</tmp/tmp.txt>
31770 execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], [/* 123 vars */]) = 0
31770 dup2(3</tmp/test.sh>, 255)        = 255</tmp/test.sh>
31770 write(1</tmp/tmp.txt>, "hello\n", 6) = 6
31770 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7ffff7fd19d0) = 31771
31771 write(2</tmp/tmp.txt>, "./test.sh: line 3: whatfuckis: c"..., 49) = 49
```

Notice the `open` and `dup2` system calls are performed inside pid `31770`, the child of the `sh -c...` command, before actually executing `test.sh`.

## Duplicating the file descriptors in the parent instead of the child

It is possible (depending on the implementation of your shell) that the duplication will be performed on the parent level before performing the `clone`. In that case, the parent will need to save the original **STDOUT** and **STDERR** file descriptors, and restore them after the child terminates.

```
$ grep -E 'dup2\(|clone\(|execve\(|(open|write|close|openat)\(.*tmp.txt|F_DUPFD|exit_group' trace.log
1094  execve("/usr/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "./test.sh > tmp.txt 2>&1"], 0x7fffd0324118 /* 20 vars */) = 0
1094  openat(AT_FDCWD, "tmp.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3</tmp/tmp.txt>
1094  fcntl(1</dev/pts/0>, F_DUPFD, 10) = 10</dev/pts/0>
1094  dup2(3</tmp/tmp.txt>, 1)          = 1</tmp/tmp.txt>
1094  close(3</tmp/tmp.txt>)            = 0
1094  fcntl(2</dev/pts/0>, F_DUPFD, 10) = 11</dev/pts/0>
1094  dup2(1</tmp/tmp.txt>, 2)          = 2</tmp/tmp.txt>
1094  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f844aa71690) = 1095
1095  execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], 0x7f844aa9dc08 /* 20 vars */) = 0
1095  fcntl(3</tmp/test.sh>, F_DUPFD, 10) = 10</tmp/test.sh>
1095  write(1</tmp/tmp.txt>, "hello\n", 6) = 6
1095  write(2</tmp/tmp.txt>, "./test.sh: 3: ", 14) = 14
1095  write(2</tmp/tmp.txt>, "whatfuckis: not found", 21) = 21
1095  write(2</tmp/tmp.txt>, "\n", 1)   = 1
1095  exit_group(127)                   = ?
1094  dup2(10</dev/pts/0>, 1</tmp/tmp.txt>) = 1</dev/pts/0>
1094  dup2(11</dev/pts/0>, 2</tmp/tmp.txt>) = 2</dev/pts/0>
1094  exit_group(127)
```

See how before running each `dup2` at the beginning, the parent (pid `1094`) duplicates file descriptors 1 and 2 into file descriptors 10 and 11 respectively (using the `fcntl` system call and the `F_DUPFD` command) .

Then after the child (pid `1095`) completes, the parent restores file descriptors 10 and 11 (the original **STDOUT** and **STDERR**) back to file descriptors 1 and 2.